# Cross platform network aware clipboard

Tags: windows, ubuntu, clipboard, cross-platform

Do you know of any network-aware cut'n paste (clipboard) tool between Windows (XP min) and Linux (Ubuntu) - Need to free scarce brainpower resource consumed by retyping dodging strategies.

Comment: What environments are you working between - ie: virtualised instances, a terminal window, RDP??

Comment: just a row of 3 laptops (6 OS if you count the virtualised ones).  On a given box, there's no difficulty to share clipboards between guests and hosts and guests among themselves, regardless of the OSS (thx in that case to VirtualBox).  True I could rdp on each box from a central keyboard.  I'll give synergy a go. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd case used by a friend, but just in case it fits your scenario.  He has different computers in physical proximity connected by network and wanted to share the keyboard and mouse. He decided to try Synergy http://synergy-foss.org/ It was serendipity that it also allows for copy and paste between computers. Again a very specific case where the boxes, and screens are near each other and the goal was to cut it to one keyboard.

If it's just remote access, I just copied something in an UltraVNC viewer on Windows, and pasted it locally, and did the same from Ubuntu using remote desktop viewer.

Comment: Dennis, I have to thank you again...  It works like a breeze !!!

Comment: After a redirect, it looks like Synergy's current URL is https://symless.com/synergy